# 2 columns in homepage wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, multiple-columns

I modifying a wordpress template to be left with two columns on the main page with the following structure:

[image]

But the first 4 are of a category and the last 4 of another

The index code is:

http://pastebin.com/dMC0saBN

The page is (Columns are made, but all they do is repeat the post. They haven't order or filter)

crossfitlascondes.cl

Comment: can you share the link?

Comment: the link of the page?... [http://crossfitlascondes.cl](http://crossfitlascondes.cl)

Comment: just to be sure... does this image display what exactly you require?
http://content.screencast.com/users/AnkurMantri/folders/Jing/media/e0b12327-a30f-4691-8575-864436bb0cc8/00000056.png

Comment: If this question is solved, please provide the answer to it below and accept it. Placing [solved] in the title is not an acceptable way of answering a question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I occurred was to create two loops on the page and separated by , one to right column and one to left column. And so I can handle the code for each loop independently without interfering with the other column.

The code of index is:

```
    <?php get_header();?>
<div id="contentslide">
    <?php
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/slide.php');
        ?>
</div>
<?php
    get_sidebar();
    ?>
<div id="content">
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
    <div id="contentleft">
    <div id="noticias">Noticias</div> 
    <?php if ( is_home() ) { query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-27'); } ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="postleft" id="post-<?php
            the_ID();
            ?>">
            <div class="title">
                <h2><a href="<?php
                    the_permalink();
                    ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php
                    the_title();
                    ?>"><?php
                    the_title();
                    ?></a></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="postmeta">
                <span class="author">Posted by <?php
                    the_author();
                    ?> </span> <span class="clock">  <?php
                    the_time('M - j - Y');
                    ?></span> <span class="comm"><?php
                    comments_popup_link('0 Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments');
                    ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="entry">
                <?php
                    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                    ?>
                <a href="<?php
                    the_permalink();
                    ?>"><img class="postimgleft" src="<?php
                    bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');
                    ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php
                    get_image_url();
                    ?>&amp;h=150&amp;w=200&amp;zc=1" alt=""/></a>
                <?php
                    } else {
                    }
                    ?>
                <?php
                    wpe_excerpt('wpe_excerptlength_index', '');
                    ?>
                <div class="clear">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
        endwhile;
    ?>
    <?php 
        endif; 
    ?>
    <?php
        wp_reset_query();
        ?>
    <div class="navigation">
        <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Entries') ?></div>
        <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('Next Entries &raquo;','') ?></div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div id="contentright">
    <div id="wod">WOD Diario</div>  
    <?php if ( is_home() ) { query_posts($query_string . '&cat=27&'); } ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="postright" id="post-<?php
            the_ID();
            ?>">
            <div class="title">
                <h2><a href="<?php
                    the_permalink();
                    ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php
                    the_title();
                    ?>"><?php
                    the_title();
                    ?></a></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="postmeta">
                <span class="author">Posted by <?php
                    the_author();
                    ?> </span> <span class="clock">  <?php
                    the_time('M - j - Y');
                    ?></span> <span class="comm"><?php
                    comments_popup_link('0 Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments');
                    ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="entry">
                <?php
                    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                    ?>
                <a href="<?php
                    the_permalink();
                    ?>"><img class="postimgright" src="<?php
                    bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');
                    ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php
                    get_image_url();
                    ?>&amp;h=150&amp;w=200&amp;zc=1" alt=""/></a>
                <?php
                    } else {
                    }
                    ?>
                <?php
                    wpe_excerpt('wpe_excerptlength_index', '');
                    ?>
                <div class="clear">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php
        endwhile;
        ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php
        else:
        ?>
    <h1 class="title">Not Found</h1>
    <p>Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
    <?php
        endif;
        ?>
    <div class="navigation">
        <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Entries') ?></div>
        <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('Next Entries &raquo;','') ?></div>
    </div>
    <?php
        wp_reset_query();
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
    get_footer();
    ?>
```

and the code CSS(summarized) is

```
#content {
    float:left;
    width: 665px;
    height:100%;
    padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin:23px 0px 0px 15px;
    display:inline;
    overflow:hidden;

    }

#contentleft {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    height:100%;
    display:inline;
    overflow:hidden;

    }

#contentright {
    float:left;
    width: 44%;
    margin-left: 23px;
    height:100%;
    display:inline;
    overflow:hidden;

    }

#contentslide {
    float:left;
    width: 665px;
    height:100%;
    padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin:35px 0px 0px 15px;
    display:inline;
    overflow:hidden;

    }
```